# Why does the subscriber work fine when using the Hive broker but not with the local Mosquito broker or Bevywise broker?

Tags: c++, arm, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using the DISCO_L475VG_IOT02A with Mbed MQTT library using c++. The subscriber worked fine when I was using the HIVE MQTT community broker hosted on cloud. Now when I have hosted a local Mosquitto broker on a private LAN, My callback function is not getting invoked. I can publish data to it and even subscribe to a topic. I can see that the mosquitto broker is sending the packet to the IP Address of my hardware, but nothing happens. Same was the case when I hosted bevywise broker on my private LAN. What can be the cause of this problem?

Thank you.

Steps which I have already tried:

1. Tried Debugging the code to see whether the function is getting invoked.
2. Checked with wireshark to see if the broker is sending packets to the hardware.
3. Checked if the hardware is successfully subscribed to the topic.

Comment: New Findings: The hardware subscribes to the free mosquitto broker on cloud, but not on the locally hosted mosquitto broker.

Comment: Without seeing any code or config for the broker it's going to be nearly impossible to help here. Have you tried a different client (e.g. mosquitto_sub) to subscribe to the same topics?